# Using a simple JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a `posts` table with `id` column and more, and a `votes` table with `post_id`, `value` columns and more. Each `post_id` can be repeated in the `votes` table.

Now I want to select the most voted posts (and the number of votes) from the database, and I've tried the next:

```
$query = "SELECT p, SUM(v.value) FROM {$wpdb->posts} p, wp_wti_like_post v JOIN p.id  v.post_id WHERE 1=1";
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
var_dump($myrows);
```

but it retrieves an empty array.

*Note: `{$wpdb->posts}` is the correct table for the posts*

Comment: It probably retrieves nothing because of the various errors in this query.

Comment: Join syntax is wrong to begin with, it should be 'SELECT ... FROM x JOIN y ON x.id=y.other_id WHERE ...
Also I can't understand why you would put where 1=1

Comment: you should use `$wpdb->show_errors();` to troubleshoot the query

Comment: What is the `value` column in `votes` tables? Is this a numeric field representing value of vote for post - like 10 for post_id 1, 20 for post_id 2 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by post.id to get a proper sum per post. Then you can sort descending by that sum and get the first row (= highest value).

```
SELECT 
  p.*, /* Not sure if this will work. Maybe you have to 
          specify exact fields you need, although MySQL
          is pretty forgiving. */
  SUM(v.value) AS number_of_votes
FROM 
  {$wpdb->posts} p 
  INNER JOIN wp_wti_like_post v ON v.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY
  p.id
ORDER BY
  SUM(v.value) DESC
LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: You must to select only fields in table "p" that will be grouped, isn't it?

Comment: In real, er, other databases, yes, but in MySQL you need not to. That said, I think it is more readable to do so and bad in general to use `*`. But since I don't know the fields of `p`, I took the liberty to do it like this. :)

Comment: @ManoloSalsas change inner to left join so using inner join if there are no votes for posts then no posts will be shown

Comment: You can change the limit, for instance to 10 to get the 10 most voted posts.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested that, but it should work for you.

```
SELECT {$wpdb->posts}.*,wp_wti_like_post.*, SUM(wp_wti_like_post.value) as Svalue 
FROM {$wpdb->posts}
JOIN wp_wti_like_post ON wp_wti_like_post.post_id = {$wpdb->posts}.id
```